# RAM is underclocked?

Tags: memory, desktop-computer

I wanted to upgrade my RAM so I checked it's specifications from Piriform's Speccy and it shows an ambiguity (sort of)? I've attached an image describing the problem.

What should I be looking for when I next buy RAM? A 1600MHz one or a 1066 MHz one? And if my RAM is under-clocked, how can I bring it up to it's max frequency?

DRAM frequency shows 532 MHz meaning 1066 MHz but in Slot-1 description it shows PC3-12800 meaning 1600 MHz.

[image: DRAM frequency shows 532 MHz meaning 1066 MHz but in Slot-1 description it shows PC3-12800 meaning 1600 MHz]

Comment: It is entirely possible that your CPU does not support the same higher speed that your memory module does.

Comment: Why would you take a photo instead of a readable screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DDR3 standard frequency is 1066 MHz, any frequencies higher than that is considered overclocking. If your mobo supports XMP, enable it will allows your RAM to run at max speed.

But still, you'll not likely experience any difference between 1066 MHz and 1600 MHz. Just buy 1066 MHz RAM if you don't intend to do any specialized work.

Comment: I was asking this for a friend who's planning to buy the RAM for gaming. Will it have any difference in gaming performance if he buys the 1066 MHz instead of 1600?

Comment: The speed difference will be unnoticeable in everyday tasks. Only when you do very specialized works that the speed difference will be noticeable.